# Can we able to update a particular cell in csv file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

Can we able to update a particular cell in `csv` file using `Javascript`?

Can anyone share please share the sample `javascript` code?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Whats your problem? SO wont do it for you. We can help, but for that you need a bit a more concrete question.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a `workbook`, here is how you may loop through the rows and change the cell value:

```
var rows = workbook.sheets[0].rows;
for (var ri = 0; ri < rows.length; ri++) {
    var row = rows[ri];
    for (var ci = 0; ci < row.cells.length; ci++) {
        var cell = row.cells[ci];
        cell.value = new_data;
        cell.hAlign = "left";
   }
}
```

**Update**

```
var file = document.getElementById('docpicker')
file.addEventListener('change', importFile);

function importFile(evt) {
  var f = evt.target.files[0];

  if (f) {
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = e => {
      var contents = processExcel(e.target.result);
      console.log(contents)
    }
    r.readAsBinaryString(f);
  } else {
    console.log("Failed to load file");
  }
}

function processExcel(data) {
  var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
    type: 'binary'
  });

  // inject your logic as per need
    var rows = workbook.sheets[0].rows;
    for (var ri = 0; ri < rows.length; ri++) {
        var row = rows[ri];
        for (var ci = 0; ci < row.cells.length; ci++) {
            var cell = row.cells[ci];
            cell.value = new_data;
            cell.hAlign = "left";
       }
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you please update the complete code here. Would be much helpful

Comment: Hi Bilal,Could you please let me know which library we could use for reading the data in csv like ExcelJs or var workbook = new $.ig.excel.Workbook(); Could you please help me to choose the csv workbook  library .

Comment: You may go through the code provided in accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57059227/read-a-csv-or-excel-xlsx-file-with-just-javascript-and-html/57059503

Comment: My ask is i need to write a local csv file at a particular cell.The link you shared is something fetching data from a server. can you suggest alternative to write a csv file please,

Comment: Look at var file = document.getElementById('docpicker')
it is getting your file from a file picker control

Comment: that answer has what you need, you can take it from there, just read carefully